# Global try/catch implementation in scala

Tags: scala, try-catch

I am trying to look for the Global try/catch method for all my methods to handle the exception and return the same.

```
private def myMethod() {
     try {
       methodThatThrowsIOException() 
     } catch (IOException e) {
       //What to do?   
     }
   }
```

So, rather then separately calling try catch in each method , can I design a common method which will handle try/catch exception for my all other methods in scala.
here I need to make `myMethod()` generic and pass any `methodThatThrowsIOException()` .

Comment: Please provide the return type of `myMethod`. Without it it's not clear what you expect to be returned. If return type.

Answer (score 1):

When passing blocks to a function, especially when that function is then used all over the place with different inputs, I tend to separate it into its own parameter list:

```
private def myMethod[T](block: => T): Try[T] = {
    Try(block())
}
```

This is often easier to read, e.g.:

```
val result = myMethod {
  // your code
}
```

You then match on result for Failure in order to access the exception as you've asked for. If there's never a return type on `methodThatThrowsIOException` then you can further simplify and maybe use an `Option` instead of `Try`.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement an higher order function that receives everything you'd need (sort of a template pattern). Something like this

```
private def myMethod[T](block: => T, errorHandling: Throwable => Any) {
     Try(block()) match {
       case Success(s) => s
       case Failure(e) => errorHandling(e)
     }
   }
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to say `errorHandling: NotFatal => Any`. We shouldn't be handling `Throwable`.